# Strage message in PostgreSQL log "incomplete startup packet" when run in Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a PostgreSQL standalone server running on Kubernetes. I noticed I got the following messages in the log:

```
incomplete startup packet
```

now I read some articles on the web and StackOverflow and it seems it could be related to a client that tries to connect to the service to check its status. For this reason, I wrote a liveness and readiness check like this:

```
readinessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - /postgresql/readiness.sh
  initialDelaySeconds: 45
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 10
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - /postgresql/liveness.sh
  initialDelaySeconds: 45
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 10
```

where the scripts `/postgresql/liveness.sh` is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep postgres | wc -l) -lt 11 ]; then
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi
```

and `/postgresql/readiness.sh` is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
su - user -c "/var/user/packages/postgres-11.9/bin/psql -p 2544 -d postgres -c \"SELECT 1\"" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The problem is that I still see the message in logs and I don't know how to check if the two probes are working.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. If you deploy PostgreSQL on Kubernetes and expose it as a service on a Cloud platform, you need to use a load balancer.
This load balancer checks the healthiness of your application send health packets to the PostgreSQL port and since it is not a valid PostgreSQL command, the application reply with the message above.

IBM Cloud doesn't provide any solution to this and I think the message can be ignored. To make it less annoying just set the interval check to the right value (in my case 60s instead of 5s). The higher the value the less annoying it will be, however, it will be less reactive to failures.

In addition, to avoid uncontrolled Kubernetes probe provide always:

- readiness probe
- liveness probe
- start probe

In my question, you can see how to define it for PostgreSQL. The only one not mentioned is start probe you can define in this way:

```
startProbe:
  exec:
    command:
      - /postgresql/liveness.sh
  initialDelaySeconds: 45
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  periodSeconds: 10
```

for startProbe is OK to use the same liveness script since the application can be considered started when all processes are up and running. However, a live and started process doesn't mean it is able to accept the connection, and here is where the readiness probe comes into action.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you what exactly causes the messages in your case, but you get that error message if something establishes a TCP connection to the database server and then sends garbage rather than a valid startup packet.

The first four bytes of the message are interpreted as the length of the message by the PostgreSQL server. If the message is shorter than that, you will get that error.

You can change `log_line_prefix` so that PostgreSQL logs the client IP address (`%h`), then you know from where the connection originates. You'll have to figure out what on that machine does that. Often it is a monitoring program that just checks fir TCP connectivity without actually establishing a database connection.

Comment: The problem comes from the Kubernetes worker node (I have only one) I see its IP address. I think it is a monitor probe from Kubernetes and this is the reason why I write two new probes from scratch. But this didn't solve the issue.
Now I don't know how to check my probes are running and if there is another probe I am not aware. It test the 2544 port that is the one I exposed on container. It is not a standard port so I am pretty sure Kubernetes knows it and test it periodically.

Comment: Checked my Pod and I noticed the Kubectl describe command provides info about the liveness and readiness tool that are working right now. They are the ones I wrote.

Comment: That tool is not very smart then - it should establish a database connection.

Comment: The liveness and readiness tools work properly. Running them manually in the Pod they work properly. They run not very frequently while the monitor tool that causes the issue is very frequent. This is the reason why I think it could be another Kubernetes tool but I don't know what.

Comment: I think I solved the issue. The monitor tool comes from the network load balancer. It tested every 5 secs the 2544 port. Now I think this test is important for the load balancer to check if the application is healthy. The problem is that it only allows TCP and HTTP tests with no customization. I am not sure how this is supposed to work with general no HTTP application like PostgreSQL.

Comment: Another thing I learned is that there is also a startProbe to use for applications slow to start. In my case the liviness.sh script is ok to use also for this probe.

Comment: If you don't mind the message in the log, you can simply ignore it. It is not a problem that needs to be solved.

Comment: Yes I arrived to the same conclusion.

Comment: @SalvatoreD'angelo, please write your solution as an answer, and accept it, so this question won't stay as unaswered.